# How to allow video uploader to delete other user's comments on their videos

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am trying to allow a video uploader to be able to delete comments left under their video by other users. Everything I found so far is only about the comment author only being allowed to delete their own comments but nothing about someone else.

React/redux w/  rails backend.

```rb
  def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])

    if @comment.user_id == current_user.id 
      @comment.destroy
      render :show
    else
      render json: ['Only author may can delete comments']
    end
  end
```

Comment: you can check first current_user is video owner then you can allow them to delete it

Comment: it wil like this `@video = current_user.videos.where(id:params[:video_id])` then `if @video.present?` allow to delete comment

Comment: [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit)

Comment: @MarkMerritt `pundit` and `cancancan` will work great with this kind of feature

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic change would be to do something like:

```rb
def destroy
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    video = @comment.video # I assume you have an association for this

    if @comment.user_id == current_user.id || video.user_id == current_user.id
      @comment.destroy
      render :show
    else
      render json: ['Only author may can delete comments']
    end
end
```